# multi times execute SQL 'desc dataBaseName.tableName' usage much memory

Tags: sql, hive, jvm

I want to query  hundred thousands table's column meta data in hive;after executed ten thousands,the memory come to 7G from 3g;the simple query with multi times execute,usage so much memory,and it's still rising;I tried to set hive.query.results.cache.enabled with false,but it didn't work;

Comment: The problem are the man columns and usually you don't need all. Everycolum needs some space and the achier number, is the problem, check you design and see if you can optimize . Also for that size you should look for server with at least 128 gigabyte and some multicores

Comment: Sorry，I must need this meta to handle my lsp complete；now，my only way is querying metastore connection directly，but the metastore datasource is changable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to check the query and if all columns in the join and where are in combined indxes